# AJAX POST with express.js - newlines removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

The script I use for sending the request:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
       var form = e.currentTarget;
       console.log($(this).serialize());
       $.ajax({
           url: form.action,         
           type: 'POST',                                             
           data: $(this).serialize(), 
           success: function(response) {renderGraph(response);},
           error: function() {}
       });  
       e.preventDefault();
});
```

The server route:

```
app.post("/sendDL", function(request, response) {
      var _graph = new graph(request.body.DLCode);
}
```

Using `x=1;y=2;` as input, I get `DLCode=x%3D1%3By%3D1%3B`.

Using `x=1;\ny=2;` as input, I get `DLCode=x%3D1%3B%0D%0Ay%3D1%3B`.

Both yield `x=1;y=1` in `request.body.DLcode`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you specified `app.use(express.urlencoded());`?

Comment: @mccannf, that doesn't do anything but I did notice something. a handler using `search` does find the newline, it seems that perhaps the newline just don't show in the watched variable in VS2012. Will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a total dummy.

It does go through, I was debugging in VS2012 and the debugger is of the opinion that newlines are not important.